# Chain rule for [scalar to matrix to scalar]

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Background: I'm trying to implement an Expectation Maximization algorithm for Gaussian Processes. In the M-step, I'm taking the derivative of the likelihood with respect to the parameter(s) of the kernels. I'm wondering how to update the parameters in the following context:

$$ \sigma \in \mathbb{R}, \qquad  K : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}, \qquad  f: \mathbb{R}^{m \times m} \to \mathbb{R} $$

We can think of $\sigma$ as the parameters for the kernel (e.g. Gaussian Kernel), $K$ as the Kernel matrix, and $f$ as the likelihood function.

I'm having difficulty with getting the dimensions to work out when evaluating
$$ \frac{\partial f(K(\sigma)) }{\partial \sigma}$$

Can someone help with this? I'm trying to solve this using a "chain rule" approach, but the dimensions don't seem to make sense in the  context of the problem. Specifically, I seem to be getting a $m \times m$ matrix instead of a scalar.

Comment: For the dimensions in chain rule to be correct, you'll need to use tensors. Instead try to explicitly define $f\circ K:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ since using $m\times m$ dimensions is abundant. I am not sure of specifics of either, so consider this as a suggestion only.

Answer (score 2):

By identifying the space of $m$-square real matrices $\operatorname{Mat}_m(\mathbb R)$ with the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^{m^2}$, meaning we "straighten out" the matrix into a column vector, we obtain the following chain of functions:
$$\sigma \in \mathbb R \xrightarrow{\quad K\quad } \mathbb R^{m^2} \xrightarrow{\quad f \quad} \mathbb R. $$
The chain rule applies as in standard multivariable calculus:
$$\frac{d(f \circ K)}{d\sigma}(\sigma) = \sum_{j=1}^{m^2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y^j}(K(\sigma)) \frac{d K^j}{d\sigma}(\sigma); $$
as you can see, this quantity is a scalar, as we would like to see since $(f \circ K) : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't explicitly show either of the functions, I'll assume that you don't need help calculating their **matrix-valued** gradients
$$\eqalign{
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\s{\sigma}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\deriv#1#2{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\grad{K}{\s} \quad{\rm or}\quad \grad{f}{K} \\\\
}$$
Write the differential of $f(K),\:$ do a change of variables,
then recover the derivative wrt $\s$
$$\eqalign{
df &= \gradLR{f}{K}:\c{dK} \\
  &= \gradLR{f}{K}:\c{\gradLR{K}{\s}\,d\s} \\
\deriv{f}{\s} &= \gradLR{f}{K}:\gradLR{K}{\s} \\
}$$
where a colon denotes the matrix inner product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \} \\\\
}$$

Answer (score 0):

Applying the chain rule to the composition $f\circ K$,  we have $D(f\circ K)(\sigma)=Df(K(\sigma))\circ DK(\sigma)$.

Writing each component out gives  $\sum^{2n}_{i=1}\frac{\partial f}{dx_i}(K(\sigma))\cdot \frac{dK_i}{dt}(\sigma)$, which is a scalar.

(Actually, $D(f\circ K)(\sigma):\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is a linear transformation $T$ which is identified with $T(1).$)